# (gnu)plotting multiple series with volatile source

Tags: gnuplot

I have a program that produces some data series, let's say they are formatted like

```
t1 x1 y1 z1
t2 x2 y2 z2
t3 x3 y3 z3
    ...
tN xN yN zN
```

I usually would plot them with

```
plot "data.data" u 1:2, "" u 1:3, "" u 1:4
```

I would like to call directly the program when loading data

```
plot "< source_programs" ...
```

The problem is, the program produces random data, so I tried to use the `volatile` keyword, but the program is reloaded for every data series.

Is it possible to do this with gnuplot? Maybe buffering somehow the data without the need to call the program again?

Comment: can u explain more your problem, it seems unclear for me, you have two programs ? one produce random data ? and the other read it ?

Comment: No, the program is just one and produces random series :)

Comment: Besides random, the data could also be generated with a heavy computation. This question fits the scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to "buffer" the data is in a temporary file:

```
!bash source_programs > temp.dat
plot "temp.dat" u 1:2, "" u 1:3, "" u 1:4
!rm temp.dat
```

Comment: Well, from the help pages I read I suspected that a buffer file was the only option... But at least I learned something new: `!bash` :) Thanks

Comment: There's also `shell` and `system` which can be used too.

Comment: As additional suggestion, I would recommend using `src="\`mktemp\`"` and plot `src` instead of directly using "temp.dat". This helps in preventing possible race-conditions when running parallel instances of the command.